# Is it Okay to Download Various Libraries and Read Their Documentation from 3rd Party Websites?

Tags: java, dependencies, documentation

I need to Download the dependencies and documentation of Unirest Java library from [Jar-Download](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/all-versions) which is a thrid party website, because I can't find the docs on its [offical website](http://unirest.io/java.html) and I want an easy way to download all its dependencies without using Maven.
So the question is that is it okay to use such sites.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and ask more specific about programming issue itself.

Comment: You should really learn to use Maven or Gradle. They make life so much easier.

Comment: This is a legal question, and so is off-topic for stack-overflow. Also, on their site (http://unirest.io/java.html) is a link to the jar, and a link to the EULA (MIT)